# Solve equation of complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I have encountered such a question that I am not sure how to solve it:

> $z= a+bi$, where a and b are real numbers, solve the equation $\bar{z}^5 = z$ ($\bar{z}$ is the conjugate of $z$)

- **The question also gives two hints: $cos(\pi/3)=\frac{1}{2}$ and
  $sin(\pi/3) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$**

However, I am not sure how to use these two hints?

I managed to find the solution in a reverse way: I found that if $z =\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i $ would satisfy the equation of this question.

But I was not able to find this solution from the equation $\bar{z}^5 = z$

Comment: Why not use polar form instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you multiply both sides by $\overline z$ you get
$$\overline z^6=|z|^2$$
The right side is real and nonnegative, so the left side must be as well.  The magnitude of the left is $|z|^6$ so we know that $|z|=0$ or $1$.  $\overline z$ and therefore $z$ must be $0$ or one of the sixth roots of $1$.